# What is Partial Pressure Resistance?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, resistance

While trying to design a power bank circuit, I came across a handy SOC IC `IP5306`. Looking through its datasheet ([available here](http://www.injoinic.com/wwwroot/uploads/files/20200221/0405f23c247a34d3990ae100c8b20a27.pdf)), I found the term `Partial Pressure Resistance` in the following text at the bottom of page 9.

[image: Text taken from the bottom of page 9 of datasheet available at http://www.injoinic.com/wwwroot/uploads/files/20200221/0405f23c247a34d3990ae100c8b20a27.pdf]

I never heard what partial pressure resistance is. My search on Google didn't offer me a useful source to understand about it. If someone knows about it, please provide information about it.

Comment: I think it's a bad translation, but of what I cannot say.

Comment: I think it's to do with current negotiation over USB?

Comment: Could pressure be a mangled interpretation of voltage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These resistors are required for some devices which will only start charging when specific voltages are met on the USB data lines.

As shown in your image it is basically a voltage divider for the DP and DM nets which are connected to the second usb port. The first port as provided by the example circuit from the datasheet just shorts the data+ and data- lines. But for some devices this will result in not taking a charge from such a port.

Answer (score 5):

The [Chinese language datasheet](http://www.injoinic.com/wwwroot/uploads/files/20190219/f801f35149ce32d45826167cd7eeb8b1.pdf) says:

> 输出不接分压电阻时虚线框 内电路可以省略

Which Google.com and Yandex.ru translate to:

> When the output is not connected to the voltage divider resistor, the
> circuit in the dotted frame can be omitted

Comment: Guessing that the manufacturer's translator got "partial" where "divider" would have been more accurate, and "pressure" where "voltage" would be the right option. This is why you hire *technical* translators for stuff like this, who go out of their way to learn terms of art and jargon, not just the same translators you'd hire for marketing consumer products.

Comment: @Hearth Yes, the equivalent in French-English I guess would be translating power supply voltage as "nourishment tension".